# PyDev colors - what is this color called and how do I change it?

Tags: eclipse, colors, pydev

I'm using Eclipse 20190917-1200 with PyDev for Eclipse 7.4.0.201910251334. Whenever I move my cursor into a key word it's highlighted as shown below. I can't find this color anywhere in the PyDev settings. One question is, what is that behavior called, but more importantly, how can I change that insane color!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `general > editors > text editors > annotations > Occurrences (PyDev)` and change the colour or uncheck it.

Hope this works for you !!